# numpy.array_equal and numpy.testing.assert_array_equal does not compare NaNs as equal when dtype is object

Tags: python, numpy

What is the proper way to compare np.nan when dtype is object?
I tried the following two approaches, but both failed

#### 1. np.array_equal

```py
import numpy as np
np.array_equal(np.array([np.nan], dtype=object), np.array([np.nan], dtype=object), equal_nan=True)
```

What I got is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\xxxx\xxxxx\.venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 2455, in array_equal
    a1nan, a2nan = isnan(a1), isnan(a2)
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

#### 2. np.testing.assert_array_equal

```py
import numpy as np
np.testing.assert_array_equal(np.array([np.nan], dtype=object), np.array([np.nan], dtype=object))
```

What I got is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Users\xxxx\xxxxx\.venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\_private\utils.py", line 932, in assert_array_equal
    assert_array_compare(operator.__eq__, x, y, err_msg=err_msg,
  File "c:\Users\xxxx\xxxxx\.venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\_private\utils.py", line 842, in assert_array_compare
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: 
Arrays are not equal

Mismatched elements: 1 / 1 (100%)
Max absolute difference: nan
Max relative difference: nan
 x: array([nan], dtype=object)
 y: array([nan], dtype=object)
```

#### NumPy/Python version information:

1.20.3 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: NaN by definition is not equal to any number including NaN. You might replace all null values with None and then do the equality test

Comment: `array_equal` is trying to handle `nan` correctly, but `isnan` only works with float dtype (and it's not allowed to convert your object dtype).  It's well known that math on object dtype arrays is hit-or-miss.  This one of the misses!

Comment: In my use case, the array may contains strings along with np.nan.
Do you have any ideas to get this done?

Comment: For example, `np.array(['a', np.nan], dtype=object)`